# sudo asks twice for the password

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, pam

On ubuntu 14.04, I had a problem with my user authenticating on a domain of my company over ldap, and the IT guy played about with some configuration files and packages. Now, on a local user, whenever I execute a command with `sudo` the prompt asks twice for a password.

I've been searching quite extensively through the Internet, and cannot find the solution. I've tried every possible solution: all the PAM configuration files have been reset, as well as `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. I have uninstalled and purged all the packages related to `ldap`, have checked `/etc/hosts`and `/etc/sudoers`... but the problem remains.

The only two significant clues that I can provide is that this only happens on the command line (if I execute synaptic from with the GUI, the system only asks me for the password once), and it seems, from `/var/log/auth.log`, that pam_unix.so is being invoked only once, so PAM seems to be ok.

How can I trace the origin of this problem?

Comment: This might be the same issue: [Sudo asks for password twice with LDAP authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/220603/sudo-asks-for-password-twice-with-ldap-authentication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem. What was confusing me is that I thought that

> pam-auth-update --force

was overwriting completely all the PAM configuration files (`/etc/pam.d/common-*`), so that those files would end up as if they were brand new. But it does not. What `pam-auth-update`does is to overwrite all the text of those files up to the *last line of the default configuration file*, which actually reads `# end of pam-auth-update config` (I had failed to realise that it was quite self-explanatory). Anything written by the user before that line is overwritten, but everything that appears *after* that line is not touched by the update.

For some reason the lines

> @include common-auth 
>   @include common-session 
>   @include common-session-noninteractive

that are called by PAM when executing the service `sudo`, had been pasted at the very end of the `common-session-noninteractive` file, and updating PAM was not deleting them. They were making PAM ask for the password a second time.